# How to plot graph from a text file values using gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

How to plot a graph from text file values? The text file look like below:

```
location  count1    count2
HZ        100        193
ES        514        289
FP        70         137
BH        31         187
```

I want to plot these values as a graph in shell script. In x axis values of location column and y axis values of count1 and count2 column.

Comment: The obvious `plot "/tmp/temp.txt"` fails with `Bad data on line 1 of file /tmp/temp.txt`. I think you may just have to create a version of the file with just numbers, no row/column headers. Alternatively, use something like gnumeric.

Answer (score 10):

Using the same input file (ex.tsv), and creating a gnuplot script to 
better control the details

```
set style data histogram 
set style fill solid border -1
plot for [i=2:3] '/dev/stdin' using i:xtic(1) title col
```

and gnuploting the data:

```
gnuplot -p ex.gnu < ex.tsv
```

we see the correspondent histogram.

To create a png file (to upload and show in SO) add 2 more lines:

```
set terminal pngcairo enhanced font "arial,10" fontscale 1.0 size 600, 400 
set output 'out.png'
set style data histogram 
set style fill solid border -1
plot for [i=2:3] '/dev/stdin' using i:xtic(1) title col
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Working solution for **gnuplot** v5.0:

Input data file `loc.dat`:

```
location  count1    count2
HZ        100        193
ES        514        289
FP        70         137
BH        31         187
```

---

*gnuplot* script `locations.plt`:

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot -persist

set title "Location data"
set xlabel "location"
set ylabel "count"
set grid
plot "loc.dat" u (column(0)):2:xtic(1) w l title "","loc.dat" u (column(0)):3:xtic(1) w l title ""
```

---

- `set title "Location data"` - main plot title
- `set xlabel "location"` - setting label for `x` axis
- `set ylabel "count"` - setting label for `y` axis
- `set grid` - adding grid to the plot
- `(column(0)):2:xtic(1)` - column range, `(column(0))` - as the 1st column in the input file has non-numeric values we need to imitate the numeric 1st column as gnuplot expects only numeric values in it
- `w l` - means ***with lines***, to join all data points *with lines*

---

Interactive launch:

```
$ gnuplot
gnuplot> load "locations.plt"
```

---

Rendered result:

[image]

Comment: Just wanted to mention, note the quotes around locations.plt in the command `gnuplot> load "locations.plt"`, gnuplot requires that, `load locations.plt` will not work and you will get "internal error : STRING operator applied to undefined or non-STRING variable" if you forget it.